# Analytics: how to use Activity (Task / Event) in a Dataset?

Tags: event, activities, analytics, analytics-cloud, einstein-analytics

I'm setting up Analytics / Salesforce Wave and trying to report on Events.
 The use case here is these Event records are used as a mechanism for logging billable hours.

Unfortunately, I can't see any of these objects from the Dataset Builder interface:

- Activity
- Task
- Event

What's the best bet for enabling these objects in Analytics? Load them in as external data?

[image: dataset-builder]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't believe these objects are supported by Salesforce Analytics as per the Wave Data Integration Guide - Page 15. You can also see Unsupported Salesforce Objects and Fields via below link

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=bi_integrate_salesforce_extract_transformation_unsupported_objects_fields.htm&language=en_US

Import into Wave - Best practise here would be external load / middleware

Comment: Andrew is 100% correct :-) Sorry I didn't check the limits before the post :-)

Answer (score 3):

FYI, Task and Event objects are now supported by native Salesforce Analytics Cloud dataflow. Now, you should be able to view these objects in the Dataset builder.

Answer (score 2):

It may simply be that the dataset builder interface doesn't support it, because the activities objects are a bit special (they have their own special datamodel to support the way they can have variable associative relationships https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_erd_activities.htm). I have not verified myself yet, but I suspect you can manage this by manually scripting the JSON for the ELT.